# How to conditionally handle dynamic select options using react?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-hook-form

I'm currently working on a form for a React project using `react-hook-form`, where I have a field array that contains a select and an input. I want to be able to dynamically change the options available on the select when a new field is added.

**EDIT:** here is a CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-twxu1

Comment: Could you show the code more specifically

Comment: I will try to make a codesandbox

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not just have one "select box" where you can select multiple values? For instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component

Comment: i can't have select multiple values since every field in the field array must contain only one option selected and in every field the options selected must be different

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button type="button" onClick={() => append(
          {
                firstName:options[2]
              }
)}>
                Append
              </button>
```

You need to have one counter which will be increase on button click and you can replace that 2 with the count.

Comment: what I want is when a new field is added the select in that field will only show the options that have not been previously selected